# True/False Statements about Commutative Rings with Unity. CSIR(2019)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Which of the following is true:

> 1. If $R$ has finitely many prime ideals, then $R$ is a field.

> 2. If $R$ has finitely many ideals, then $R$ is finite.

> 3. If $R$ is a PID, then every subring of $R$ with unity is a PID.

> 4. If $R$ is an integral domain which has finitely many ideals, then $R$ is a field.

The solution i tried-

1. We take the example of $\mathbb Z_{2210}$ the prime ideals of this ring are prime divisors of 2210 which are 2,3,7,11,5, but the given ring is not a field, thus we can discard this option.
2. If we take $R=\mathbb{Q}$, then this is a field (which is also a ring), the only ideals of $\mathbb{Q}$ are $(0)$ and $(1)$, but set of rational number is not finite, so we can discard 2nd option.
3. In this option we can take $R=\mathbb{Q}[x]$ which is a P.I.D. and take its subring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, and this subring is not P.I.D., so 3rd option is discarded.

The remained option is 4th which should be true (for this I can't find the example).

I am not satisfied by my approach to this question by only choosing particular examples.

Please suggest me a proper solution, and i am also  confused with term "finitely many".

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: The solutions for 1) to 3) are fine. To disproof a statement it's sufficient to give a counterexample.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edited** and corrected the answer based on Paul K's comment.

For the 4th case, let $a \neq 0$ be such that $a \in R$. Now consider the ideal $\langle a \rangle$. If this ideal is $R$, then $ar=1$ for some $r \in R$, in which case $a$ is invertible. If this ideal is not $R$, then we can create a chain of ideals
$$\ldots \langle a^3 \rangle \subset \langle a^2 \rangle \subset \langle a \rangle$$
But the number of ideals is finite, this means this chain will stabilize, i.e. $\langle a^i \rangle = \langle a^j \rangle$ for some $i<j$. Consequently, $a^i=ra^{j}$. In which case using the fact that $R$ is an integral domain and $a \neq 0$ we can  infer that $ra^{j-i}=1$. Thus $a$ is invertible. This show that $R$ must be a field.

For (1), a simple example like $\Bbb{Z}_4$ works.

For (2), any infinite field like $\Bbb{R}$ works.

Comment: If $(a) = R$, then you can only infere that there is some unit $\varepsilon \in R$ with $\varepsilon a = 1$, which is okay. How do you infere $a^k = 1$ for some $k$? Similarly in the latter case, $(a^i) = (a^j)$ implies in an integral domain that we have $a^i = \varepsilon a^j$ for some unit $\varepsilon \in R$. Now since $R$ is an integral domain we have $1 = \varepsilon a^{j - i}$ which shows that $a$ is a unit.

Comment: @PaulK you are right. I mistakenly was in the "group" mode. I will modify.

Comment: Your counter-example for $(1)$ doesn't seem to work properly because $\Bbb Z$ has infinitely many prime ideals. Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @Anacardium You are right. I have edited it. Thanks for pointing it out.